# Node-red lost connection to the server with new node

Tags: python, sparql, node-red, rdflib

I have to connect to Sparql endpoint and query RDF via Node-red. I found an add-on node called `node-red-contrib-sparql` which enables that. I am able to install the node. I downloaded python and install required libraries for nodes to work. However, whenever I deploy the flow I lose connection to server and Node-red crushes. The error is written like below in cmd window. Is there someone who encountered the same problem or any other option in Node-red to query RDF data??

[image: this appears in cmd window]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your post - you will get many more views and much better answers!

Comment: Please post the actual text of errors (and format it using the options in the toolbar) rather than pictures. The images are unsearchable and normally hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

Node-RED is crashing because the `node-red-contrib-sparql` node is not properly catching and handling the error.

You need to open an issue against that specific node (which I can't find on flows.nodered.org)